# VBA and PivotTable Filters show id but not Values

Tags: vba

please help. I have to create pivot table with filters, i can select 2 filters but when i'm trying to select third one i'm getting error, I used macro record to see how it should be done and got this:

```
"[Product].[System Source].[System Source]").CurrentPageName = _
"[Product].[System Source].&[SIMHKG_HSB]"

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields( _
"[Product].[Shareclass].[Shareclass]").ClearAllFilters

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields( _
"[Product].[Shareclass].[Shareclass]").CurrentPageName = _
"[Product].[Shareclass].&[5]"
```

as you can see in this code the Shareclass filter Value is 5, BUT in PivotTable field I see names not numbers and in VBA I want to filter it with Names not by numbers, how can i write it? Because when I use name instead of [5] i get an error. To keep it simple, when i Click to filter in cube and select something which called ABCD, in VBA i see number but no ABCD.. i need use ABCD in VBA not ID.

Thanks